# writing underscore _.reduce method using _.each

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am practicing rewriting reduce method in underscore library.

I want to make it so if no starting value is passed, the first element is used as the accumulator, and is never passed to the iterator.

I have written it to this far below. not sure how I can make the first element not to be passed to the iterator. appreciate any comments.

```
  _.reduce = function(collection, iterator, accumulator) {
    if(arguments.length == 2) accumulator = collection[0];
    _.each(collection, function(el){
      accumulator = iterator(accumulator, el);
    })
    return accumulator;
  };
```

Comment: Try doing it the other way round, that's much easier and makes more sense :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is where `_.first` and `_.rest` come in handy:

```
_.reduce = function (collection, iterator, accumulator) {
    if (arguments.length == 2) {
        accumulator = _.first(collection);
        collection = _.rest(collection);
    }
    _.each(collection, function (el) {
        accumulator = iterator(accumulator, el);
    })
    return accumulator;
};
```